# SqlDataSource not running select command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview with the a sqldatasource. I am declaring the select parameter in code behind. When the page loads the first time it is populating the data correctly. When i go to enter info into a text box and hit the add button and declare the select parameter it is not repopulating the data. If I go out of that page and go back in the new info is there. If I do not declare the select parameter in code behind and just hard code it, it works. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "spGetPartnerLeadNote"
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("leadID", lblLeadID.Text)
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: In my code behind I have the following         SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("leadID", lblLeadID.Text)
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "spGetPartnerLeadNote"
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure This is on the button click

Comment: Can you put that into the question instead of a comment so it's easier to read please? :)

Comment: When I add the select parameter in code behind it does not allow and ajax post back, If I just hard code the parameter it works. That is the only difference.

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: Try placing the text value in a string variable before the add call and check if it's null or empty before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear parameters before add ..
this works for me

```
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "spGetPartnerLeadNote"
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType=SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear()
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("leadID",TypeCode.String,lblLeadID.Text)
```